# NTFS permission issue, asking for CHKDSK frequently

Tags: windows

We have one of file server (2008 R2) in which the file permissions are getting corrupted frequently and also asking for CHKDSK to run, if we run CHKDSK it will fix the issue, but it reoccurs again in few days.
Please assist on this.

Balaji

Comment: Have you verified the physical integrity of the disk?

Comment: I agree that it sounds like you have a bad drive.

Answer (score 1):

If this company file server is important, I would go to the store for a replacement HDD and clone using {insert favorite cloning software}.

Litmus test.

Will your company lose more than $100 if the drive fails ?  If yes, then it's time to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server running RAID and if so, can you outline the RAID type, # of disks in array, and controller type/version?

There may be some underlying issues causing this.

I would recommend performing a disk check at the hardware level to start.

Please let us provide additional information so that we can better assist.